# Translate python to C#

Tags: c#, python

How would this look in C#?

```
checksum = hashlib.sha256(hashlib.sha256(address).digest()).digest()[:4]
```

Especially the last part [:4] what does it mean?

Answer (score 2):

That's a slice. It gets every position in the list from 0 to 4 (inclusive).

```
 >>> [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8][:4]
 [1, 2, 3, 4]
```